# permission denial when reading local html file in sdcard in 2.3

Tags: android, permissions, webview

When reading local html file in `sdcard`, I use this,

```
webview.loadUrl("content://com.android.htmlfileprovider/sdcard/123.html").
```

The above code can work in `2.2 emulator`, but can not work for `2.3 emulator` and gives the following information:

> permission denial：opening provider

Now, I have changed it to:

```
webview.loadUrl("file:////sdcard/123.html")
```

and it works.

I still want to know why the previous code can not work in 2.3 emulator.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, I have changed it to: webview.loadUrl("file:////sdcard/123.html") and it works.

That is surprising, considering that the path is wrong for an Android 2.3 emulator (four slashes and no `/mnt`).

Do not hard-wire directory names. Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get at the root of external storage, `File` constructors to build a complete path based off of that directory, and `Uri.fromFile()` to create a `file:///` `Uri` from that.

> I still want to know why the previous code can not work in 2.3 emulator.

That provider is no longer exported and so is no longer available for abuse. You should not have used that provider in the first place, since it was undocumented and unsupported.